# Does "10% chance to summon on kill" require using the weapon?

Tags: torchlight-2

[image]

Does this have a chance if socketed in my wand to trigger on any kill or only wand kills?

Answer (score 4):

In general, weapon socket enchants only affect that specific weapon, so you must get the kill with the weapon.  Note that skills that do % Weapon DPS damage inherit all your weapon enchants, so those count too.